# Why booking.com fully refund the amount I paid for a hotel room which I confirmed?

Tags: bookings, booking.com, payment

I did not cancel my booking but I am not sure why booking.com fully refund the amount to my account. The hotel I m going to stay asked for my credit/debit card number to secure my reservation which I have no choice I give it to them and they said they will reserve the room for me.

I really confused. I just wondering is my booking confirmed or not. Anyone can advise me.

Comment: Have you contacted Booking.com to ask why?

Comment: Yes but booking.com reply was  "For payment-related questions, or other queries regarding your stay, you can message the property directly" which I did email to the hotel, they said they will reserved the room for me since I already gave my debit card number to them and informed me to pay by card or cash when I check in.

Comment: If your emails to the hotel were as confusingly written as this question you may have ended up with two bookings ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can only be resolved by booking.com or the hotel, who have the details of the actual transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Some properties on booking.com don't accept prepayment, but rather you use a credit card online to guarantee your booking, and in the hotel you make the payment. This is true by smaller private properties and by properties marked "cash only".

However, you can contact booking.com for prepayment options in certain cases.